# Laravel 5.7 schedule via cron on AWS EC2 linux ami - commands not running

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created a cron job in AWS EC2 but it is not working at scheduled time.when i run command in cli `php artisan schedule:run` it is working fine but not execute automatically at scheduled time.

php version=7.2.11

laravel framwork = 5.7

I added cron entry in crontab using `crontab -e`

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

This is my kernal file

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands=[
    '\App\Console\Commands\ExampleCronJob',
];
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('example:mail:send')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `which php` on your server?

Comment: php version is 7.2 and output will be nothing because command not execute at every-minute@Mozammil

Comment: `which php` will output the path to your php executable. Just want to make sure you got the right one.

Comment: i try with php7.2 in path but still not working@Mozammil

Comment: Just type `which php` in your terminal while logged in to your server and let us know the output. It should show something like `/usr/local/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: `/usr/bin/php`  @Mozammil

Comment: Added my answer :)

Comment: /usr/bin/php using this i solved my problem thanks @Mozammil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our comments, the issue is with your PHP executable's path. The path is wrong in your cron job definition. Change it to:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Assuming that the `artisan` executable is located at `/var/www/html`, that should fix it.

*In case you are not sure if that's the correct path, you can type `pwd` from your project root (where artisan is located) to get the correct path to your artisan executable.*